# Configure zsh prompt to show only first 2 letters of current directory

Tags: zsh, macos, prompt

I would like to display only the first two letters of the current directory.

I tried

```
PROMPT="%1d %# "
```

which displays the current directory as `directory1`. But taking a subset of the directory as the first two characters and displaying as the `zsh` prompt in MacOS is where I am lost.

How do I only get the first two characters, i.e. `di` instead of `directory1` as the `zsh` prompt instead?

Comment: What if you have `dir $` and you `cd` to `directory2`? Is it  now `dir/dir $`?

Comment: As a general advice, you can get your prompt to be "anything", if you define `cd` as a function, in which you calculate an updated prompt.

Comment: @Kaz - with `zsh` you can use a [`precommand`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104574/9307265) to execute arbitrary code to set the prompt.

Comment: On MacOS, a home directory usually has several standard subdirectories.  Two of them are named `Documents` and `Downloads`.  Since they have the same first two letters, your prompt won't tell you which one you're in.  Are you sure you don't want the prompt to be the first three or four letters of the directory name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `%2>...>` truncating operator to truncate `%1~` (the last component of the current  working directory with `~` representation) or `%1d` if you don't want the tilde representations:

```
$ PROMPT='before %2>>%1~%>> after%# '
before ~ after% cd /usr/local
before lo after% cd ~sys
before ~s after%
```

Or to show that there has been some truncation:

```
$ PROMPT='before %3>✀>%1d%>> after%# '
before ch✀ after% cd /usr/local
before lo✀ after% cd /
before / after%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
setopt promptsubst
PROMPT='${${(%):-%1d}[1,2]}%#'
```

This is a set of nested `zsh` expansions, which can be a bit challenging to read at first.  Some of the pieces:

- `setopt promptsubst`- with this enabled, `zsh` will expand the `${..}`s in the prompt.
- `PROMPT='...'` - sets the prompt. The single quotes are important; we do not want to evaluate the `${...}` expansions until later.
- `%#` - `#` if root, `%` otherwise.
- `${:-...}` - this is a way to get a constant string (`%1d`) into a nested expansion.
- `${(%)...}` - percent sequences are processed as prompt sequences. We need this since the `${...}` expansions took us out of 'prompt world' into 'normal variable world'.
- `%1d` - the last component of the current directory. For `/a/b/c/ddd`, this will be `ddd`.
- `${...[1,2]}` - the first two characters in the string. Note that arrays in `zsh` start with index `1`.

There is [more](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) [information](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion) in the [`zsh` documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/index.htm).

Comment: When using `promptsubst`, you need to make sure `%`s (and possibly `!` if `promptbang` is enabled) are escaped in the expansions. See for instance after `mkdir %Bar; cd %Bar`